# Can D3.js be used to manage door-to-door canvassing?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, openstreetmap

I need to develop a street mapping system to plan for door-to-door canvassing. This software would need to be able to identify walking routes prior to canvassing and then record them as having been covered.

Does anyone know if this has been done? or if it is feasible using d3.js or other mapping software?

Comment: I'm sure that this would be feasible using D3, but I'm not sure if the question is appropriate here -- are you struggling with anything in particular?

Comment: D3 would a best be a small part of the solution -- remember it is just a visualization tool!  You would need more complex software to determine routes, and you would need some sort of database that could be updated as they are covered.  You might want to look at the Google maps API...

Comment: This is probably the wrong forum for this question. The short answer is that d3 is not likely to be helpful in this regard - you want a real GIS system that can do the routing for you. You might try asking about such systems on http://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Lars, I am looking for tools to manage door-to-door street maps. Perhaps I shouldn't have posted this question here. Can you think of somewhere suitable?

Comment: AmeliaBR I understand that D3 is a visualization tool and other components would be needed. I just wanted to find out if there were options I had overlooked.

Comment: nrabinowitz - thanks for the suggestion of stackexchange.